# How to create Client certificates for Azure?

Tags: https, azure, client-certificates

I have created HTTPS endpoint for my Cloud application (using Self signed certificate). One of the requirements of my application is requirement of Client Certificate. When i run my application i do not see a list of Client Certificates to choose from.

Does anyone have any idea on what Client Certificates are required & how they can be created?